# How to get data from multiple SharePoint groups with one query in Graph Explorer?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, office365api

Basically I need to get Information from Multiple Groups in one Query.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{I Need Multiple ID-s Here}/conversations
```

The Microsoft Graph explorer only lets me get conversations from one group with one query. In my case, I have 6, and I want to get the last conversations at the same time. If I delete the ID I get an Error that the Query needs an Object Identifier. Is there a Multi-Object-Identifier? Can this even be done with the Graph explorer? If not, is there another way? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try batching:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/json-batching

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch
```

body:

```json
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/groups/{first-group-id}/conversations"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/groups/{second-group-id}/conversations"
    }
  ]
}
```

pnpjs has a built-in support for batching (a bit more convenient), if you use it.